# Why is the function result value of r2_score slightly different from the function result value of score?

Tags: scikit-learn

I am asking because the results of the two functions are different during the process of designing a model using random forest regression and evaluating it through coefficient of determination. The random forest regression score function described in sklearn and r2_score are called functions that calculate the same coefficient of determination. I think I've entered the right order of parameters, but I don't know why there's a different result. I need your help.

My Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from google.colab import drive 
drive.mount('/gdrive', force_remount=True)

data = pd.read_csv(r"/gdrive/MyDrive/Coal_Inert_Case/FI_S_Case_1_40_2.csv")


X =data[['press1', 'press2', 'press3', 'press4', 'press5', 'press6', 'press7', 'press8', 'press9', 'press10', 'press11', 'press12', 'press13',
 'press14', 'press15', 'press16', 'press17', 'press18', 'press19', 'press20',]]
   
y = data[['C_Sieve 16000', 'C_Sieve 11000', 'C_Sieve 8000', 'C_Sieve 5600', 'C_Sieve 4000',
       'C_Sieve 2800', 'C_Sieve 2000', 'C_Sieve 1400', 'C_Sieve 1000', 'C_Sieve 710',
       'C_Sieve 500']] 

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3,random_state= 42)

forest = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1000,random_state= 42) 
forest.fit(X_train, y_train) 

y_pred = forest.predict(X_test)
r2 = forest.score(X_test, y_test)

from sklearn.metrics import r2_score 
r2_y_predict = r2_score(y_test, y_pred)

print('R2: ', r2)
print('R2 Score: ', r2_y_predict)
```

The output is:

```
R2:  0.8814689389660927
R2 Score:  0.919250867792171
```

Comment: What version of sklearn?

Comment: `r2_score` and `forest.score` should return the same value. You might have overwritten a variable in your Google Colab or it might be as Ben Reiniger suggested a scikit-learn's version problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are using an older version of sklearn, and the difference is due to your **multioutput** regression problem.

In the documentation of `RandomForestRegressor.score`:

> **Notes**
>
> The `R^2` score used when calling `score` on a regressor uses `multioutput='uniform_average'` from version 0.23 to keep consistent with default value of `r2_score`.

The default for `r2_score` was changed in 0.19, but for `RandomForestRegressor` it [was set to use](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/4256542b10bcc6bd10ddf31dfb356ecc084f2e7d) `variance_weighted`.